# Get file name from stats object

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I use the `fs.stat` for getting information about file, now I want to get the file name from the stats object, I did some searching and I didnt find anything help.

I will explain my code now, maybe someone will find another solution, this is all my code:

```
function index(response, lang) {
temp.loadTpl('templates/' + lang + '/content.html', function (content) {
    fs.readdir('files/', function (err, files) {
        temp.loadTpl('templates/' + lang + '/files.html', function (data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var i, fnames, len = files.length, filesNamesHTML = '';
            fnames = files;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                fs.stat('files/' + files[i] , function (err, stats) {
                    console.log(i);
                    if (stats.isFile()) temp.write('TYPE', 'file-o');
                    else temp.write('TYPE', 'folder');
                    temp.write('FNAME', fnames[i]);
                    filesNamesHTML += temp.transTpl(data);
                });
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                temp.write('FILES', filesNamesHTML);
                response.write(temp.transTpl(content));
            }, 100);
        });
    });
});
}
```

The relevant part is:
I use `fs.readdir` to read directiony files, and I run over the result with loop,
And for every file I run stat function like that:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   fs.stat('files/' + files[i] , function (err, stats) {
      temp.write('FNAME', fnames[i]);
    });
}
```

The problem is in this: `fnames[i]`, until that the callback invoked, the `i` variable is changed, and I always get the same result for every file.

Maybe you have a solution how the get the file name inside the `stat` callback function.

The problem happend because I try to use the Async functions...

**EDIT:**
I thought on solution, who wants...

You can put the `fs.stat` function into a function and to pass this function the file name, and use it inside the `stat` callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your EDIT should solve the problem of variable scoping. You haven't explained it very well, but I know what you mean.

You've got a `for` loop, which is synchronous, but you're using it to start asynchronous functions. Then you're waiting until all files have been `fs.stat`ed before doing the final part, by assuming that `fs.stat` won't take more than 100ms. As asynchronous things go, `fs.stat` probably isn't too slow, so 100ms *should* be enough time unless you have a large number of files. However, when you're doing things that are slower and/or take a variable length of time, you'll want to control the timing more tightly so that it does the last bit immediately after it's finished the last of the async bits.

There are npm modules for this kind of management of asynchronous functions. I'm going to answer using the `async` module, because that's the one I know, but there are equally valid ways of doing it with other modules using promises.

I'd do it like this:

```
var async = require('async');

function index(response, lang) {
    temp.loadTpl('templates/' + lang + '/content.html', function (content) {
        fs.readdir('files/', function (err, files) {
            temp.loadTpl('templates/' + lang + '/files.html', function (data) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                var i, fnames, len = files.length, filesNamesHTML = '';
                fnames = files;
                async.each(files, function(file, done) {
                    fs.stat('files/' + file , function (err, stats) {
                        console.log(i);
                        if (stats.isFile()) temp.write('TYPE', 'file-o');
                        else temp.write('TYPE', 'folder');
                        temp.write('FNAME', fnames[i]);
                        filesNamesHTML += temp.transTpl(data);
                        done(null);
                    });
                }, function() {
                    temp.write('FILES', filesNamesHTML);
                    response.write(temp.transTpl(content));
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

(Then do `npm install async` .)

There are other things I could change, but this is tricky stuff the first time you see it so I'll refrain. Suffice it to say that it's worth exploring the `async` module or something equivalent if you want to write javascript code involving multiple calls to asynchronous functions.

Comment: Hey @DavidKnipe I like your answer, Nice to meet the `async` module, did it have a documentation?